# zoho mail API getting Invalid OAuth Scope Scope does not exist

Tags: php, email, zoho

My URL request:

> https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/auth?scope=organization.accounts,accounts,ZohoMail.messages.READ,ZohoMail.messages.CREATE,ZohoMail.messages.UPDATE,ZohoCRM.users.READ&client_id=1000.Y6O7LWZG5UXXXXX42OMR0TUJE&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=https://example.com/callback.php

The PHP code:

```
$grantToken = $_GET["code"];
$clientID = '1000.Y6O7LWXXXXXXXXMR0TUJE';
$clientSecret = '3edec1c3453XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX4e9dfcdd62bf62d6';
$refreshToken = '1000.a89707967c7166XXX993cde9e55c6.202e0d0b39ecd5XXX5f97527de0';
$redirectURI = 'https://example.com/callback.php';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "refresh_token=".$refreshToken."grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=".$clientID."&client_secret=".$clientSecret."&redirect_uri=".$redirectURI."&code=".$grantToken);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);

$response = json_decode($response, true);
$accessToken = $response['access_token'];
$refreshToken = $response['refresh_token'];

print_r($response);
echo $response['access_token'];

$senderAddress = 'my@email.com';
$accessToken = $response['access_token'];

// -- get zoho accountid --
$ch2 = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/user/info");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken ".$accessToken;
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch2);
if (curl_errno($ch2)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch2);
}
curl_close ($ch2);
echo "success";
print_r($result);
/*
$result1 = json_decode($result, true);
$accountId = $result1['ZUID'];

echo "<br><br>";
print_r($result1);
echo "<br><br>";
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info);
echo "<br><br>";


// -- get mail
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mail.zoho.com/api/accounts/$accountId/messages/search?query=from:'".$senderAddress."'");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken ".$accessToken;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

//$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
//print_r($info);
//echo "<br>";

$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

I've tried contacting zoho but they couldnt help me. I have the free tier zoho mail and crm etc

Comment: Looks like your Client ID is wrong. Try creating a new Client and copy paste the Client ID.